# Rails Bootstrap confirm delete using Sweetalert

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sweetalert

I am trying to replace my "confirm" delete with SweetAlert.

This works fine currently to delete the observer with the normal alert dialog. I'm not sure how to call the sweetalert.js.

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm pretty new to this!  Thanks!

**team.html.erb**

```
               <td>
                 <div class="btn-group">
                   <%= link_to "/members/observers/#{observation.id}", class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger", method: :delete,  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  do %>
                       <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove Observer"></i>
                   <% end %>
                 </div>
               </td>
```

**sweetalert.js**

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that sweetalert gem is installed and seems to work fine.

Comment: Update.  I am now calling the sweetalert.js by adding a "sweet_delete" class to the btn.  So it opens the sweetalert prompt, but it continues with the delete regardless of what option is chosen in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` are included in your **`application.js`** file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and install  `'jquery-rails'` gem if you didn't yet.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

then run `bundle install`

I believe you're good to go! :)